# Why doesn't an input field change update angular model?

Tags: angularjs

This is a very newbie question but why doesn't

```
    document.getElementById("demo").value
```

update angular model? It updates the input field, but it updates the model only after manually putting something into the field.

Here's the code:

```
<div ng-controller="AddCtrl">
  <input type="text" id="demo" ng-model="test.fld" ng-change="change()"></input>
  <br />

  [ <a href="" onclick="somefnc()">pop</a> ] 
  [ <a href="" ng-click="add(test)">add</a> ]       
  <p>Test-field: {{test.fld}}</p>
</div>



<script>
  function somefnc() {
    document.getElementById("demo").value = "hi";  
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Did you get this to work? I tried the idea below but it still does not update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is purely related to the way angular binds data.  The simplest answer would be, after manually changing the form data, $scope.$apply() must be called for the element's scope.  Called outside the "Angular world" you could change somefnc to:

```
function somefnc() {
    document.getElementById("demo").value = "hi";
    $('#demo').scope().$apply();  
}
```

Best practices say that any direct dom manipulation should happen only in directives.  Ideally, you would change this value in the controller with something like:

```
$scope.somefnc = function(){
    test.fld = "hi";
}
```

Anything done through the angular scope like this does not need $scope.$apply, only direct dom manipulation does.

The full example is here

```
<div ng-controller="AddCtrl">
  <input type="text" id="demo" ng-model="test.fld" ng-change="change()"></input>
  <br />

  [ <a href="" ng-click="somefnc()">pop</a> ] 
  [ <a href="" ng-click="add(test)">add</a> ]       
  <p>Test-field: {{test.fld}}</p>
</div>



<script>
angular.module('app').controller('AddCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope/test = {fld: ''};
    $scope.add = function(){
        $scope.test.fld += test.fld
    }
    $scope.change = function(){
        alert('I changed!');
    }
    $scope.somefnc = function() {
        $scope.test.fld = "hi";  
    }
}])
</script>
```

Comment: I'm trying to trigger validation after changing the value of the input on a site that has validation. The scope apply does not trigger the validation. Is there something else I can use to trigger the validation in the case of the html here: <input id="shippingAddr-first-name" type="text" class="first-name ng-pristine ng-valid" maxlength="16" data-ng-model="addressTypes[addressType].FirstName" focus-me="commonAddressTypeProps[addressType].focusOnFirstName" client-validation="onExit" data-required-on-exit="">

Answer (score 0):

Because AngularJS can only watch the model change in AngularJS's **scope**. So you need to modify using Angular's way not other ways like jQuery if you want the 2-way data binding magically work.